# Merging Javascript Files based on rules

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript project for my company and have a question about handling/managing files.

Is there a feature where you can work locally on the main file with different files at different cases:

## live.js

```
/*Code for live deployment*/
```

## test.js

```
/*Code for test deployment*/
```

But if you "make" it gets merged on a certain pattern which I can decide e.g.:

## main.js

```
if(flag=true) { /*Code for test*/ }
   else          { /*Code for live*/ }
```

I hope you get what I want to achieve, a modularity in the development to make it more manageable.

thank you in advance
best regards

Comment: [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if)

Answer (score -1):

There are frameworks for migration, testing and development.

For example I used [truffle framework](http://truffleframework.com/) to create different test and life environments while working with blockchain.

Comment: Ok please leave a comment for downvote so that the answer can be improved